# Why Chromium consumes high CPU in Puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm running chromium for some testing a Linux Ubuntu 20 machine.

Whenever it's used I'm having huge CPU usage.

htop shows Chrome at around 95% on a 2 VCPU machine.

I'm launching Chrome from NodeJS Puppeteer application :

```
const {launch, getStream }  = require("puppeteer-stream");
const fs = require("fs");
const {exec} = require("child_process");

async function MyFunction() {
    const browser = await launch({
        headless:true,
        defaultViewport: null,
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto("https://www.somepage.com");
    const stream = await getStream(page, { audio: true, video: true, frameSize:50});
    console.log("recording");
        
    // do some stuff with ffmpeg
        
    setTimeout(async () => {
        await stream.destroy();     
        
        stream.on("end", () => {});                 
        return;
    }, 1000 * 30);
}
```

Here is the command shown in htop :

```
/home/ubuntu/node_modules/puppeteer-stream/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/chrome-linux/chrome 

--type=renderer 
--disable-dev-shm-usage 
--disable-background-timer-throttling 
--disable-breakpad 
--enable-automation 
--force-color-profile=srgb 
--remote-debugging-port=0 
--field-trial-handle=6176443002177110407,6471108360500070252,131072 
--enable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess 
--disable-features=Translate 
--enable-blink-features=IdleDetection 
--lang=en-US 
--user-data-dir=/tmp/puppeteer_dev_chrome_profile-TNWVrc
--disable-client-side-phishing-detection 
--whitelisted-extension-id=jjndjgheafjngoipoacpjgeicjeomjli 
--num-raster-threads=2 
--enable-main-frame-before-activation 
--renderer-client-id=6 
--no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations 
--shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
```

Does anyone know how to make Chrome use less CPU please ?

Thanks.

Comment: Creating a video is one of the most CPU challenging tasks there are. Is there an option to change your approach to some testing and make screenshots or use a testing framework maybe?

Comment: That's true. Still, creating the video is not what is consuming CPU. It's Chrome instead. The excessive CPU usage happens when Chrome is open. Otherwise, the business need is to capture the video of the browser and stream it. Hence, can not be replaced by screenshots.

Comment: This is a list of all Chromium flags: https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/.  Might find something useful.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose since you start puppeteer in headless mode where HTML5 MediaRecorder API cannot be used, it just creates a ton of screenshots to feed into ffmpeg thus generating severe CPU load.

Try to run it headfully, using Xvfb:

```
xvfb-run -a node ./test-script.js
```